# How can i make the input editable again?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to make a number converter that instantly converts without the need of pressing a button.
 Here's the code so far on codepen, please test it(use the decimal input first than use the binary one, **ignore the octal and hex they aren't functional yet**):

https://codepen.io/ahmadbenos/full/eYprJyW

```
    const binary = document.getElementById("binary");
const octal = document.getElementById("octal");
const decimal = document.getElementById("decimal");
const hex = document.getElementById("hex");

var binaryIsClicked = false;
var octalIsClicked = false;
var hexIsClicked = false;
var decimalIsClicked = false;

var decimalConvert = setInterval(convertDecimal, 50);

function convertDecimal() {
  binary.value = Number(decimal.value).toString(2);
  octal.value = Number(decimal.value).toString(8);
  hex.value = Number(decimal.value).toString(16);

  if (decimal.value === "") {
    binary.value = "";
    octal.value = "";
    hex.value = "";
  }
}
  binary.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearInterval(decimalConvert);
    binaryIsClicked = true;
    var binaryConvert = setInterval(convertBinary, 50);

    function convertBinary() {
      decimal.value = parseInt(binary.value, 2);
      octal.value = parseInt(binary.value, 2).toString(8);
      hex.value = parseInt(binary.value, 2).toString(16);

      if (binary.value === "") {
        decimal.value = "";
        octal.value = "";
        hex.value = "";
      }

    }
    });
```

So here's the problem, if you first type a number in the decimal field = working normally

after that you go to the binary input field and edit/type a new number = working normally

after that, you go again to the decimal input field but if you try to edit/type you can't, it's stuck on the previous interval (the binary interval).

What's the problem ? i tried clearing the binary interval after clicking on the decimal field again but it's not working.

Comment: May I suggest you use the onkeyup event instead of polling with setInterval? That might do it all for you.

Comment: @Yishmeray yes this case should have no use to time intervals, I have posted an answer, I know this question has already an accepted answer but i wanted to let it for futture peoople those want to do the same, and maybe the OP will change his mind after seeing my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `"onchange"` event instead of making time intervals, as pointed out by [**Yishmeray**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10987633/yishmeray) in his comment, but I prefer to listen to `"oninput"` event in this case, because the user wants to see quick result while changing the input and still focused on so `".onchange"` will not trigger unless the user finished typing and focused on something else, and this can be done in less code, and avoiding code repetition, so I made this example it does what you want and even prevents the user from entering wrong number depending on the base in a user friendly way (no alerts or warnings)

```js
var [bin, oct, dec, hex] = document.querySelectorAll("form input");
bin.oninput = oct.oninput = dec.oninput = hex.oninput = function(e) {
  var base, val;
  switch(e.target.name) {
    case "bin": base = 2; break;
    case "oct": base = 8; break;
    case "dec": base = 10; break;
    case "hex": base = 16;
  }
  val = Number(parseInt(e.target.value, base));
  if(isNaN(val)) return [bin.value, oct.value, dec.value, hex.value] = ["","","",""];
  [bin.value, oct.value, dec.value, hex.value] = [val.toString(2), val.toString(8), val.toString(10), val.toString(16)];
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px lightgreen, 0 0 1px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font: bold 20px monospace;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Binary Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="bin">
  <label>Octal Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="oct">
  <label>Decimal Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="dec">
  <label>Hexadecimal Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="hex">
</form>
```

Comment: This is much better. I had no idea that there was an event called "oninput". I'm new to javascript. Things would have been much easier if i've started with the oninput thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There I fixed it:

```
    //elements
const binary = document.getElementById("binary");
const octal = document.getElementById("octal");
const decimal = document.getElementById("decimal");
const hex = document.getElementById("hex");

//have no idea what these are for
var binaryIsClicked = false;
var octalIsClicked = false;
var hexIsClicked = false;
var decimalIsClicked = false;

//intervals not set yet, will be in event handlers functions

var decimalConvert;
var binaryConvert;



//event handlers
decimal.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  //sets decimalConvert interval and clearing binaryConvert interval
  decimalConvert = setInterval(convertDecimal, 50);
  clearInterval(binaryConvert)
    console.log("decimal clicked " + decimalActive)
})
binary.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  //sets binaryConvert interval and clearing decimalConvert interval
  binaryConvert =  setInterval(convertBinary, 50)
  clearInterval(decimalConvert)
  console.log("binary clicked " + binaryActive)
})

//functions for event handlers
function convertDecimal() {
  //convert decimals to other types
  binary.value = Number(decimal.value).toString(2);
  octal.value = Number(decimal.value).toString(8);
  hex.value = Number(decimal.value).toString(16);

  console.log("function convertDecimal executed")

  if (decimal.value === "") {
    binary.value = "";
    octal.value = "";
    hex.value = "";
  }
}
function convertBinary() {
  //converts binary to other types
      decimal.value = parseInt(binary.value, 2);
      octal.value = parseInt(binary.value,         2).toString(8);
      hex.value = parseInt(binary.value, 2).toString(16);

  console.log("function convertBinary executed")

      if (binary.value === "") {
        decimal.value = "";
        octal.value = "";
        hex.value = "";
      }
}
```

What you did right was `clearInterval` for decimal. However you didn't do it for binary. So you add a second event listener for `console.log` to check your work I used it to see which intervals were and weren't executing to solve this issue.

Comment: @AhmadBenos Take a look on my post